# Como ejecutar un script en php sin boton o form

Tags: php, codeigniter, script

Tengo un scritp que se ejecuta al presionar un botón, pero quisiera ejecutarlo dentro de un if, dejo el código de lo que tengo, espero puedan ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Este es el script que quiero ejecutar se encuentra en el index

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function printParking(parking_url)
    {   
      $.ajax({
        url: parking_url,
        type: 'get',
        success:function(response) {
          var mywindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'height=400,width=600');
          mywindow.document.write(response);
          mywindow.document.close();
          mywindow.focus(); 
        setTimeout(function(){
             mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close(); 
        },300);


        }
      })
    }
</script>
```

Actualmente lo ejecuto de esta manera en el index:

```
<a onclick="printParking('<?php echo base_url('parking/printInvoice/'.$v['parking']['id']); ?>')" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir Ticket</a>
```

pero quisiera ejecturalo dentro de este if que esta en el index tambien:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, ¿En que momento deseas ejecutarlo?

Comment: actualmente lo ejecuto con un boton, pero quisiera ejecutarlo por ejemplo si se cumple la condicional de un if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera, no creo que sea la adecuada, pero tal vez solucione tu problema.

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>

 <script>

     printParking('<?php echo base_url('parking/printInvoice/'.$v['parking']['id']); ?>')

 </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por contestar, lo probe de esa manera pero no ejecuto nada :/

Comment: podes colocar una foto de la consola de google? Presiona F12 y te vas a la pestaña de Console

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, tuve que crear otro pero sin el Ajax pasándole la ruta directamente y si agarró, muchas gracias Alonso